# Edit Android project remotely (FTP) using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project checked out from git into an ubuntu server. I will be doing git check-in and check-out files inside this ubunut machine.

I have installed Android studio in my local system .i.e. windows machine.

Is it possible to use FTP in Android Studio to directly import the project from ubuntu server and edit them without copying to my local windows system. I did search around the internet and couldn't find any posts regarding how to do this.

I'm aware that we can install Android studio in Ubuntu itself, but I'm not allowed to do that.

It would be very helpful if anyone throws some light on this.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? If yes, can you please share?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) is only available on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, which Android Studio is based on. It looks like the server only stores the files and IDEA on the client does the heavy lifting. For Android, there's also the question of running emulators, which I assume is also done on the client.

Not sure what the delta is between AS and IDEA, but you can develop Android apps on it.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is not enough, you need something like [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) that allows a user on a client computer to access files over a computer network much like local storage is accessed.